# Add CAGradient Layer behind UIImageView iOS

Tags: ios, core-graphics, mapkit, mkannotationview, cagradientlayer

I am trying to add a gradient behind a transparent image. I do this on the map leftCallOutAccessoryView however no matter what I try the gradient layer always shows above the imageView and want it to appear behind it

heres my code for MKAnnotationView which is an ivar called pinView

```
pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

UIImageView *profileIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Profile.png"]];
pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = profileIconView;

CAGradientLayer *backgroundLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
backgroundLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
backgroundLayer.cornerRadius = 2;
backgroundLayer.borderWidth = 1;
backgroundLayer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
backgroundLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[sharedManager cellGradientEnd] CGColor], (id)[[sharedManager cellGradientStart] CGColor], nil];
[profileIconView.layer insertSublayer:backgroundLayer atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure it out using the below, in short I create a empty view then add the imageView as a subview to the view and now its all sweet!:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
UIImageView *profileIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Profile.png"]];
pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = view;

CAGradientLayer *backgroundLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
backgroundLayer.frame = view.bounds;
backgroundLayer.cornerRadius = 2;
backgroundLayer.borderWidth = 1;
backgroundLayer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
backgroundLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[sharedManager cellGradientEnd] CGColor], (id)[[sharedManager cellGradientStart] CGColor], nil];
[pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView.layer insertSublayer:backgroundLayer atIndex:0];
[view addSubview:profileIconView];
```